# Creating an app with applescript

Tags: mac, applescript

I'm trying to make an app that when opened will play an audio file that is contained in the app, but i have no idea how to do it. I know this is really vague and I apologize but any help would be awesome.

This other question covers high level how to make an app, but I can't figure how to actually make the shell.

- [How to make a simple app from an applescript!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/13280/how-to-make-a-simple-app-from-an-applescript)

Is there a guide or sample code to show how to take an actual file and actually play it in AppleScript framework?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an *example* of one way to achieve your goal:

In **Script Editor**, I used the following three lines of *code* and saved it as an application, as **Hello World.app**:

```
set resourceName to "Hello World.aiff"

set filePathName to quoted form of POSIX path of (path to resource resourceName) as text

do shell script "afplay " & filePathName
```

Then inside the *application bundle* in the `Resources` folder, I placed the audio file **Hello World.aiff**, which is a file of someone saying "hello world".

Here is a *tree view* of the hierarchal structure of the *application bundle*:

```
Hello World.app
└── Contents
    ├── Info.plist
    ├── MacOS
    │   └── applet
    ├── PkgInfo
    └── Resources
        ├── Hello World.aiff
        ├── Scripts
        │   └── main.scpt
        ├── applet.icns
        ├── applet.rsrc
        └── description.rtfd
            └── TXT.rtf
```

Now when I *double-click* on the **Hello World.app** is plays the **Hello World.aiff** audio file.

---

**Notes:**

After you create the *application bundle*, then in **Finder** you *right-click* on it selecting **Show Package Contents** and then navigate to the **Resources** folder where you'll place your audio *file*.

Change the name of the `resourceName` from `"Hello World.aiff"`, to whatever your audio file name is, in the example *code* so it will work for your filename.